# How to find the css class and code for a graphical element (range slider) in Jupyter Lab/Notebook output cell and modify it to change its appearance?

Tags: css, python-3.x, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook, jupyter-lab

I have the following graphs/outputs from VSCode, VSCode-Insiders and Jupyter Lab respectively.

**VSCode**
[image: vscode]

**VSCode-Insiders**
[image: insiders]

**Jupyter Lab**
[image: JLab]

I want to change the looks of the slider that you see at the bottom.

Basically I want to remove the text and number and change the looks of the slider knob and its position to be in the center relative to the image.

My thought process is that, since VSCode is an electron app and Jupyter Lab runs in a browser so it should be possible to modify that single output cell with a custom targeted CSS.

As an example I have the following that works perfectly in all 3 setups and changes the CSS of the output cell by coloring the text, which tells me that it may be possible to do what I want with the slider element too -

```
%%html
<style>.css-example { color: darkcyan; }</style>
<span class='css-example'>This text has a nice colour</span>
```

But in my case I have to target a particular element - "slider". I toggled to the developer mode in VSCode and VSCode Insiders - "Ctrl+Shift+I" or "Help -> Toggle Developer Tools". But I am not able to select the slider element using the "Inspector".

In Jupyter Lab fortunately I was able to select the slider element, but the class `vega-bind` (the div that has the slider has a class called `vega-bind`) doesn't seem to have any CSS in it - at least nothing related to `vega-bind` showed up in the Developer Tool.

Is there any way to achieve what I am trying to do in Jupyter Lab and VSCode Jupyter Notebooks?

The following code generates that output that you see above -
Requirements - `altair`, `pandas` and `numpy`

```py
import altair as alt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

rand = np.random.RandomState(42)

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'xval': range(100),
    'yval': rand.randn(100).cumsum()
})

slider = alt.binding_range(min=0, max=100, step=1, name='cutoff')
selector = alt.selection_single(bind = slider, init={'cutoff': 50})

alt.Chart(df).mark_point().encode(
    x='xval',
    y='yval',
    color=alt.condition(
        alt.datum.xval < selector.cutoff,
        alt.value('red'), alt.value('blue')
    )
).add_selection(
    selector
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out Jupyter Notebooks in VSCode are rendered as iframes and are separate processes that you cannot debug/run developer tools on from the main developer tools panel that opens on the side.

To find the CSS, HTML etc of the notebook iframe, you have to open the **Webview Developer Tool** and you can do that by typing `Open Webview Developer Tools` in the *command palette* i.e.
*CTRL+Shift+P -> Open Webview Developer Tools*

Now you can select the *inspector* and hover over any element you like and see/edit its CSS.